# Expressing determinant as a linear combination of minors of fixed dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $k<n$. How does one express $\det\begin{pmatrix}a_1^1&\dots&a_n^1\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a^n_1&\dots&a^n_n\end{pmatrix}$ in terms of a linear combination of determinants
$\det\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^{i_1}&\dots&a_k^{i_1}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a^{i_k}_1&\dots&a^{i_k}_k\end{pmatrix},$
where $1\leq i_1<i_2<i_3<\cdots<i_k\leq n$?

Comment: This is indeed possible and not totally trivial. It is called *[Laplace expansion of a determinant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)*

Answer (score 1):

Just develop according to the last column $(n-k)$ times.